# VS 2010 - cannot add a TODO token - Add is disabled?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, token, todo

Deleting works, but it does not enable the option to `Add`.

[image]

Comment: @Oded: Nope, and it works the same for a brand new project.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Close the window and reopen it and don't click on any Tokens. You will see the following:
[image]

If you click on any tokens before that, ADD button will be disabled.

OR

In your screenshot you have posted, just Rename UnresolvedConflict in the textbox (below Prioity) and ADD button will be enabled.

Comment: When I open it, I have `Add` disabled, as well as `Delete` and `Change`. But I got your point - it appears that I misunderstood how it's supposed to work. Thank you - I'll mark it as an answer.

Comment: It's not the way one expects it to be (clicking on Add is the last step, no t the first one), that's the misleading thing. Good catch.

Answer (score 11):

Follow these steps,

1. Close the options page
2. Open it again and go to **Environment > Tast List**
3. Before you click on anything fill up the **Name** textbox with whatever new Token name you want to create.
4. Add gets activated. And you're sorted.